# asp.net: Should dropping dlls into the Bin folder work in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll-reference

I am using Visual Stidio 2010 Beta 2 and just started using MVC, I copied a bunch of dlls into a Bin folder and Included this Bin folder in the project. It seems that there is no reference to these dlls from Controller classes?

Is this an MVC thing, or a broken project/VS installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "included this bin folder in the project", to add a reference, you need right click the project in visual studio, click "Add Reference", then add those dlls into your project. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I would prefer to drop them in the Bin folder and have them auomatically referenced, in order to manage versions, than reference a 3rd folder. This does work in VS 2008?

Comment: OK, I have used "Add Reference" and browsed to the Bin Folder and selected those? I now have reference to those dlls, but this seems wrong? Is this standard practice?

Comment: You manage references by having something like a "libs" folder where you put all your references. Then when you add a reference you do it from that folder. If you update a reference in the "libs" folder and build the project, the new version will be used. This is usually the easiest way to handle references in a website as well. Because its better for source control tools (like svn or git). This has always been the behavior in a web application.

Comment: @Mattias Jakobsson: Thanks, it looks like we will need to take this route. Should we add this Library folder into the App_Data folder so xml and other files remain non-accessible or deleted before deployment etc? Or should this not be part of the application repository?

Comment: I usually put it outside of my project structure. I have it set up something like this: 
/[projectname] (solution file)
/[projectname]/libs (all my dependencies)
/[projectname]/[projectname].Web (the web application structure)
And then one folder for each project I have (like a core class library that is in the same solution as my web project).

Comment: just for info! what if we are to code / build / work on a project from commandline(have no access to IDE), how to reference dll then ? any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

edit - J.W. answered as I was typing. :)

Instead of dropping them in the bin folder, try right clicking on "References" and adding them using the Browse... tab.